# NativeScript app crashes while starting

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm just trying to run the Hello World app of native script on android 5.1.1. I'm compiling with android 5.0.1 and getting the following error while the app starts:

```
06-09 00:16:33.795 E/AndroidRuntime(21758): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.nativescript.testno3-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libNativeScript.so"
```

Does anyone have an idea what I have to do to make the app running? :)

Thanks

Comment: That is very interesting.    Can you open up the apk file on your computer and verify it has lib/armeabi-v7a and lib/x86 with libNativeScript.so

Comment: What phone/platform is running the 5.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify the ABIs in your `app.gradle` file to support 64-bit libraries.

It would end up looking like this:

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "your.application.id"
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
}
```

It's worth mentioning that NativeScript does not build native libraries for the `x86_64` ABI currently per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4330), so you may want to exclude `x86` and/or `x86_64`.